# How to keep the multiple lines in CSV, in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, html-table

This is a final dataframe from a CSV file I read in Python: [image: CSV input]
(except I am losing the multiple lines, descriptions are all one line)

I want to keep the multiple lines in the description as they are but Python condensed them into one line. I used pandas and numpy libraries so far. I have the option to read from CSV and xls, I am currently reading from CSV. Then I want to turn this into the following table:

Questions:

- how can I move the names on top of the description
- how can I move the seniority next to the name in large red font
- how can I group by the level as you see it looks like a pivot table
- where it says << some math calculation here >> is where I will take two values from other columns and subtract them. Ex: val1-val2

This is the desired output where the multiple lines are preserved:

[image: This is the desired output where the multiple lines are preserved]Wtdfs.png

Comment: You should edit down the code you're using to generate this to something others can try and describe what it does, what you expect it to do and how these things differ. Take a look at [MCVE] for an explanation of how to do that.

Comment: Can we think that the first table is just an input, and I just need to transform it to the table 2.

Comment: I mean, we can think that but that doesn't really explain what you're asking, what you've tried, what the exact problem is. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I move the names on top of the description?

This is simply string concatenation in Python, eg:

```
row[2] = row[1] + "\n" + row[2]
```

> How can I move the seniority next to the name in large red font

CSV doesn't provide the ability to do formatting like in a spreadsheet format as `.xls` or similar. If you export a spreadsheet in CSV format you'll see that it's formatting like bold or color is discarded.

> How can I group by the level as you see it looks like a pivot table?

You can create a dictionary like this:

```
pivot = {}
for row in rows:
  if row[3] in pivot:
    pivot[row[3]] = [row]
  else:
    pivot[row[3]].append(row)
```

> where it says is where I will take two values from other columns and subtract them. Ex: val1-val2

You can do that calculation then replace the string, eg:

```
row[2] = row[2].replace("<< some math calculation here >> ", x)
```

Comment: I think the poster might be using pandas.